# Creating a new SVN repository from a BASE repository?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, hgsubversion

I have a base repository, located at /home/bla/repo/BASE_REPOSITORY
I create a new repository, located at /home/bla/repo/new

Remember, the "new" repository already exists. I.e. I can't issue a command whereby the contents of the new one is deleted. I want to copy the BASE_REPOSITORY INTO this new repository.

Can I do this? If so, how?

Answer (score 1):

- Make an [export](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.ref.svn.c.export.html) from base (getting files without being versioned)
- Add those files to new
- Commit